# how to prevent users from writing some specific words in a textbox - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to prevent users from typing or using some specific words in a `textbox` using `JQuery` or `Javascript`? For example, I have a `textbox` and I don't want users to use words like '***Phone***', '***Home***', '***Address***' etc. Please Help.

Comment: You can `replace()` those words on keyup, although it would be a little jarring for you users as they would type `Phon` and the word would suddenly disappear after hitting the final `e`

Comment: that is exactly what I want..I don't want the users to use some specific words.

Comment: It would be better to show an error message and prevent submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be an option.

```js
var txtBox = $('#text-box');
var blackList =  ['Phone', 'Home', 'Address'];

function checkBlackList(str) {
  $.each(blackList, function(i, n) {
    if(new RegExp(n, "i").test(str)) {
      txtBox.val(txtBox.val().replace(new RegExp(n, "gi"), "xxx"))
    }
  })
}

txtBox.on('keydown', function(e) {
  checkBlackList(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="text-box" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: It does not work if I use lower case letters like phone, home, etc.

Comment: how can I make it work for words like PHONE, Phone, phone, PHone, etc...please help.

Comment: @AjmalRazeel - I have made an edit, this should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if a string contains a certain word:

```
if (yourVariable.indexOf("phone") >= 0){
    alert('you may not use the word phone');
}
```

And if you want multiple words you could create an array and loop throug it.

```
var words = ['phone', 'home', 'address', 'bobba'];
for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (yourVariable.indexOf(words[i]) >= 0){
        alert('you may not use the word ' + words[i]);
    }
}
```

and of course you can change the alert into anything you want like replace the text:

```
yourVariable.replace(words[i], 'xxx');
```

Edit i've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jx8wd1br/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by the 'yourVariable'?? Is it the id or class of the textbox??

Comment: this is the value of your textarea like: $('#mytextarea').val()

Comment: Can I replace the word with xxxx instead of using the alert??? For example, if the user types 'phone', the function should replace it with xxx.

Comment: yes of cource, you could do $("#mytextarea").val().replace(words[i], 'xxx');

Comment: I write this function but it is not working. Please Check: <script>
        $(function() {
        $(".msgbox").keyup(function() {
            
        var words = ['phone', 'home', 'address', 'number'];
            for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (.msgbox.indexOf(words[i]) >= 0){
                    //alert('you may not use the word ' + words[i]);
                    .msgbox.replace(words[i], 'xxxxx');
                }
            }
            
        });
        });
        </script>

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#txt").on("keydown", function(){
   var text = $("#txt").val();
   if(text.contains("Phone")){
     $("#txt").val().replace("Phone", "");
    }
   if(text.contains("Home")){
     $("#txt").val().replace("Home", "");
    }
   if(text.contains("Address")){
     $("#txt").val().replace("Address", "");
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: And what would you do if there are 100 words? i should make an array and a loop like in my answer. (your way works, but its not the best... no effence)

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is based on:

- array of forbidden words
- [Array forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [String indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [String replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var forbiddenWords = ['Phone', 'Home', 'Address'];
$(function () {
  $('#myTxt').on('keyup', function(e) {
    forbiddenWords.forEach(function(val, index) {
      if (e.target.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(new RegExp( "(" + val + ")" , 'gi' ), '');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" id="myTxt">
</form>
```

Comment: @AjmalRazeel Try now and let me know.